# Create an email Group

Tags: email, mutt

I am using mutt command to send an email in a shell script. I am sending it to 10 different people.

Is there a way to have those 10 email id's as a group?

Answer (score 2):

From mutt's official [docs](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#addrgroup)

> These address groups can also be created implicitly by the alias, lists, subscribe and alternates commands by specifying the optional -group option. For example,
>
> ```
> alternates -group me address1 address2
> alternates -group me -group work address3
> ```
>
> would create a group named “me” which contains all your addresses and a group named “work” which contains only your work address address3. Besides many other possibilities, this could be used to automatically mark your own messages in a mailing list folder as read or use a special signature for work-related messages.

I encourage you to read the rest of the document to see what else you can do with all the options that are available